# Why the field value in IP address shows as a link in Angular

Tags: angularjs, formatting

I have a field in a table which shows the date, for some specific values it shows a link even though I haven't added one. It seems that my data value format is like an IP address format which is starting from number 10. There are some other values which are not starting with 10, they do not have the link format.

Unfortunately, I don't have the implementation since I have done it in a specific framework for my development. I have only the following picture.

I am looking for a general answer explaining if it due to IP address format.
[image]

Comment: If you are not adding an `<a></a>` tag then it is likely the browser trying to be helpful and presenting a link.

Comment: There is no relation of link with the IP address format,So inspect the IP address that are shown as link and the other and check the difference that are we using anchor tag <a> with links. for more can you please inspect and share the screen shot of inspected element.